# Custom compile-time class loading in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, classloader

Is there a way to hook into the Eclipse compiler to specify custom class reading/resolving/loading logic while a Java source file is being compiled? I'm not sure what the correct term is, but essentially the compile-time equivalent of "class loading" that happens at run-time.

For example, say I have the Java source:

```
package foo;

import bar.Bar;

public final class Foo {
  // getQux() returns type: qux.Qux
  private final Bar bar = baz.Baz.getQux().getBar();

  [...]
}
```

The compiler should request that 3 classes are read while compiling the source file `foo/Foo.java`:

- `bar.Bar` - It is specified as an import.
- `baz.Baz` - It is used in its fully qualified form (`... = baz.Baz.getQux()...`).
- `qux.Qux` - It is an "indirect" dependency (it is returned by the call to `baz.Baz.getQux()`, which in turn is used to access a `bar.Bar` through the call to its `getBar()` method).

I'd like to be able intercept each of these "class requests" so that I can provide custom logic to obtain the class in question (perhaps it lives in a database, perhaps it it served up by some server somewhere, etc).

Also, I'd like it if no attempt was made to compile any of the source files in the Eclipse project until they are explicitly opened by the user. So in the example above, the 3 class requests (`bar.Bar`, `baz.Baz`, `qux.Qux`) aren't made until the user actually opens the source file `foo/Foo.java`. Ideally the list of source files in the project needn't be actual files on the filesystem (perhaps they too live in a database, etc) and a compile attempt is made only when a user opens/loads a source file.

I realize that, if possible, this has some drawbacks. For example, if I edit source file `foo/Foo.java` to make the class "package private", this will silently break any class that depends on `foo.Foo` until a "full" compile is done of the project. For now, that is fine for my purposes (there are things that I can do later to solve this).

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, this would fall under the Java build path part of the JDT and I don't think it has that level of customization. There does not appear to be a documented extension point for this. To get a definitive answer you would need to look at the source. You could probably add this capability and it would mean that your would need to use an alternate version of the JDT, which might be difficult or impossible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I suspected as much :(